# Sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ with $\dots\in A_3\in A_2\in A_1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In $\textsf{ZFC}$, is there a sequence of sets $A_1,A_2,A_3, \dots$ such that

$$\cdots \in A_3\in A_2\in A_1?$$

Comment: What about $\{\}, \{\{\}\},\dots$?

Comment: @avid19 Which are $A_1$ and $A_2$?

Comment: @avid19 This is a very misleading comment...

Comment: @Stefan I never said that was a correct answer. I was just probing hoping to get SOME effort out of the author.

Comment: @avid19 "I never said" even when you posted it as an answer before it is turned into a comment?

Comment: I then promptly deleted it, I meant to post it as a comment. Sorry for clicking the wrong box! @user795571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno why the down votes, seems like a reasonable question. The answer is no; this is ruled out by the Axiom of Foundation (or Regularity).

Comment: The downvotes are because no effort is shown. The author has not shared any of his thoughts. That is why I downvoted.

Comment: Typically I'd agree "no effort is shown" would be worth a downvote. Doesn't seem quite fair here: It's not the sort of question a person could really try to figure out an answer to - if he happens to know the axiom he knows the answer and if he doesn't know the axiom there's no way he could really deduce that the answer is no...

Answer (score 6):

Let me be ornery - the statement is *not* quite true. There are models of ZFC (assuming it's consistent) in which there are such sets. This is due to the Compactness Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem).

What the axiom of foundation (or regularity) rules out is having the whole sequence of sets $\{A_0, A_1, A_2, . . . \}$ exist at once - that is, the model $M$ can't "see" a descending sequence of sets. But it might have a "hidden" descending sequence of sets.

This is discussed here: [Can a model of set theory think it is well-founded and in fact not be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477715/can-a-model-of-set-theory-think-it-is-well-founded-and-in-fact-not-be)

This is exactly analogous to the idea of nonstandard models of arithmetic, where there are infinite descending sequences of "natural numbers" but those sequences can't be defined inside the model, so the induction axioms still hold. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic.

---

EDIT: let me add, for clarity:

There are two ways to phrase the question you ask.

The first is to ask: "Is there a *model* $M$ of ZFC, with elements $A_0, A_1, A_2, . . .$, such that $. . . A_2\in A_1\in A_0$?" The answer to this question is "yes," by compactness.

The second is to ask: "Is the sentence 'there is a descending $\in$-sequence' consistent with ZFC?" (More formally: "Is the sentence 'there is a function $f$ with domain $\omega$ such that $f(n+1)\in f(n)$ for every $n\in\omega$' consistent with ZFC?") The answer to this question is "no," by the axiom of foundation/regularity.

This is not an issue you want to focus on too much at first - you should begin by thinking of foundation/regularity as saying "$\in$ is well-founded." In particular, if you read this and find it confusing (which is totally reasonable!), put it aside for later; it's more important that you develop an intuition for what the "nice" (:P) models of set theory look like. But as you think more about set theory, this becomes a really interesting and important point.

Comment: The existence of such a model with such a not-quite-sequence is very interesting. Hmm, follows from Compactness, sure enough. It's not clear to me that you can conclude that "the statement" is not true. The OP did explicitly ask about the existence of a _sequence_ of sets...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich See my edit. The situation is: the answer depends on whether we ask the *external* or *internal* version of the question.

Comment: I debated with myself whether I should mention this, but decided not to as I feared this might confuse OP. Now I'm glad this has been added. Thank you, Noah.

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, I went back and forth about whether to write this. Hopefully my last paragraph softens the blow :).

Comment: @Noah Ok. I guess come to think of it the question of whether something or other exists "in ZFC" makes no real sense, the question has to be whether it exists in some model or other, and then yes we do have to consider the issues you raise.

Answer (score 2):

Let me elaborate a little on David's answer.

Consider the axiom of regularity, which may be stated as:
$$
\forall x (x \neq \emptyset \rightarrow \exists y \in x: x \cap y = \emptyset)
$$

Assume that there is such a sequence $A_1 \ni A_2 \ni \ldots$ and consider the set $\mathcal A = \{A_1, A_2, \ldots \}$. Now try show that this leads to a contradiction.

If you need additional help, just let me now. If you manage to prove it, I encourage you to show your results.

Comment: thanks. I have no problem with it.

Comment: Sometimes, a little push is all it takes, I guess ;-).

Comment: Huh, I just noticed that the upvote here is my 15,000th vote.