# Non well founded model of ZF

Tags: set-theory

I read that there are $(M,E)$ well-founded model of ZF that in fact not to be.  However I don't understand in what sense "not really to be ". I think that $(M,E)$ is well-founded  because $(M,E)\vDash (\text{foundation})$ so does "not really to be " mean that any infinite $E$-descending sequence is not an element of M ?

Comment: I'm don't think "in fact not to be" or "not really to be" is English. Are you translating the claim from a different language?

Comment: This question has come up a few times; see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477715/can-a-model-of-set-theory-think-it-is-well-founded-and-in-fact-not-be?rq=1.

Answer (score 2):

$(M,E)$ satisfies the axiom of regularity if whenever $A\in M$ is a non-empty set, then there is some $B\in M$, such that $M\models B\mathrel{E} A$, and $M\models A\cap B=\varnothing$.

In the presence of choice, this is equivalent to saying that there is no $F\in M$, such that $M\models \operatorname{dom}(F)=\omega^M\text{ and }\forall n, F(n+1)\mathrel{E}F(n)$.

But it could be that such $F$ exists *outside* of $M$. If you are familiar with ultrapowers (ultraproduct where all the structures are identical), you can show that an ultrapower of $\Bbb N$ with a free ultrafilter over $\Bbb N$ is *never* well-founded. The same argument will also work for models of $\sf ZF$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  To understand more about your answer I have some questions: 1. When you write the intersection of A and B is the empty set do you mean that $\lnot  \exists z\in M (zEA\land zEB)$? and also do $\emptyset^M $ and $\omega^M$ are defined by the same formulas that usually define them in V but relativized to M,E ? ( for example $\emptyset^M $  is an element $x\in M $ such that $\forall z\in M \lnot zEx $) finally is it correct to say that "assuming axiom of choice" is the same that V satisfies this axiom or M satisfies it ?

Comment: Yes to the first question (on all of its sub-parts); $M$ for the second question, since we're interested in something happening inside $M$ (note that the existence of such $F$ always contradicts the axiom of foundation).