# existence of transitive standard models of ZFC independent of existence of models of ZFC.

Tags: set-theory

If we consider the sentences in ZFC:

EM that express that exist a model of ZFC.

SM that express that exist a standard transitive model of ZFC.

OM that express that exist a $\omega$-model of ZFC.

By Godel second incompleteness theorem we know that  $\mathsf{ZFC}\nvdash \mathsf{EM}$

What is known about:

$\mathsf{ZFC+EM}\nvdash \mathsf{OM}$ 
 ?

or

$\mathsf{ZFC+OM}\nvdash \mathsf{SM}$ 
?

or

$\mathsf{ZFC+EM}\nvdash \mathsf{SM}$ 
?

Comment: For the second one:
Caicedo's comment here shows that $\textsf{ZFC}+\textsf{SM}\vdash\text{Con}(\textsf{OM})$, so $\textsf{SM}$ is consistency-wise strictly stronger than $\textsf{OM}$. In particular, $\textsf{ZFC}+\textsf{OM}\not\vdash\textsf{SM}$.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33688/zfc-exists-standard-model-rightarrow-conzfc-exists-omega-model?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three statements hold, as mentioned in a couple of other answers on Math.SE. The second and third one follows from Caicedo's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33688/zfc-exists-standard-model-rightarrow-conzfc-exists-omega-model?rq=1), in which he shows that $\operatorname{ZFC}+\operatorname{SM}\vdash\text{Con}(\operatorname{OM})$. For the first one, as $\text{Con}(\operatorname{ZFC})$ is absolute between $\omega$-models as mentioned in Trevor's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265379/absoluteness-of-textcon-mathsfzfc-for-transitive-models-of-mathsf?rq=1), we get that $\operatorname{OM}$ is consistency-wise strictly stronger than $\operatorname{EM}$, yielding that $\operatorname{ZFC}+\operatorname{EM}\not\vdash\operatorname{OM}$.

We thus have a strict consistency-wise ordering $\operatorname{EM}<\operatorname{OM}<\operatorname{SM}$.

Comment: thank you! ,now I understand